# HTML, CSS : Image size not proper

Tags: html, css

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which we have JSP files with HTML,CSS code inside it. Now, there is a span class with some text and image inside. The image width and height is set to 90, but the image is looking so small, almost 1/3rd the size of a thumbnail. Any idea why that is happening and what can I do to rectify it without just increasing the height and width. Thank you.

Code :

```
 <div class="span4">
            <div class="service clearfix">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign=top><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/assets/img/image.jpg" alt="Text" height="90" width="90"></td>
                        <td>
                            <p>"some texxt"
                            </p>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <small style="margin-left: 107px">Some text</small>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Now when I ctrl press the `span4`class, it shows me two different line-numbers in Intellij for bootstrap, I am posting code on both of them.

span4 class :

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
    *width: 31.861702127659576%
}
```

2nd :

```
.span4 {
    width: 300px
}
```

clearfix class :

```
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: ""
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both
}
```

Why is the image looking so small, is something wrong in CSS? THank you.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Well, according to this, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_hyassin/qjz41x5d/), the image appears fine!

Comment: @mhyassin : I saw the link you posted, but it's not looking fine, cleared my browser cache and other history as well, didn't help.

Comment: @borg: You don't see the image at all ?!

Comment: @mhyassin : I see it, but very small, like 5% the size of image I see in link you gave.

Comment: Use `max-width:100%;` in img css and remove inline width and height attribute.... `service img{
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
}`

Comment: @borg: can you mention which browser/OS you are on?

Comment: @mhyassin : Firefox 47.0 on Linux, but already tried this on Windows with chrome as well, same results.

Comment: @borg: Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_hyassin/qjz41x5d/4/), fixed or still the same?

Comment: @mhyassin : Just tried, the height has changed, but the width remains same, and it looks stretched.

Comment: @weareBorg: check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to make img tag `max-width: 100%` then your image will be responsive and you wont have problems.

So you need to add this your code:

```
table tbody tr td img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where is the max-width tag?

Comment: That is css property. So the following code will look like: img {max-width: 100%}

Comment: You are not formatting the text properly, can you please edit your answer and show me how the css should look like, your syntax doesn't seem like it's for CSS. Also, which css class to edit, I posted 3 of them. Will it have effect on any other properties which might be referring to that css.

Comment: There is no css class I have named img. Secondly, when I try to add this in the HTML code, it says attribute max-width not allowed here. I have posted 3 classes in my question, check them out please.

Comment: You are not targeting css class with this code, you are targeting img tag which is table row.

Comment: So, I added this in img tag of html code, and that's where I got an error that max-width is not allowed here. Now do you understand me?

Comment: Something like this I did : `<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/assets/img/img.jpg" alt="text" max-width="100%" height="90" width="90">`

Comment: You dont need !important here. You just need max-width 100% and that's all, then your image will be fluid and it will take proper width and height will be auto.You need to add this in css not in html

Comment: Which css class? How do I tell in html use this css class? By now I think you should understand I dont know much about html, css.

Comment: I see that. You dont need any class in here. Please take a look at here to know more about img tag in css http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the img width to 100% and the height to auto to ensure that the image is resized proportional.

Use the `!important` tag to give prio to this css tag.

```
table tbody tr td img {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

**Adding CSS to your 'project'**

Add inline CSS on your HTML page with following syntax
    
        table tbody tr td img {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
            height: auto !important;
        }

Or add it to the existing CSS file.

**Remove the width & height property on the IMG tag to prevent overwriting the CSS values**

Comment: Is this a new css class I have to add? How do I point to it in the html?

Comment: See updated answer above under 'Adding CSS to your project'. Yes, it is a new CSS class you have to add.

Comment: Just tried your class, no changes, see the screenshot I have posted, that's how its looking, those 3 black small dots.

Comment: Please remove the height="90" width="90" on the img attribute :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117701/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-daan-desmedt).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: block;` to the img css rules.

You can see a working example here:

```css
.row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
    *width: 31.861702127659576%
}
.span4 {
    width: 300px
}
.imgStyle{
  display:block;
  width:90px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="span4">
  <div class="service clearfix">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Text" class="imgStyle"></td>
        <td>
          <p>"some texxt"</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <small style="margin-left: 107px">Some text</small>

  </div>
</div>
```